# Objective C/XCode - Image in ImageView not recognised by Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, image, imageview

I am developing a simple calculator to sum the prices of 3 images in a view. These images are stored inside imageviews. The image inside each imageview can be changed using button 1-6 etc etc. The price is displayed on a label at the bottom.

I am using an if statement(s) that says if the image inside xyz imageview is @"zyx", set price as yzx.

I know the calculator works because the calculator always takes the "else" value (even if the price I set for the else value changes)

```
if(
   self.topimage.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]){

    self.TopImageView.Price = 200;
}
else if(
        self.topimage.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"slacks.png"]){

    self.TopImageView.Price = 400;
}
else {
    self.TopImageView.Price = 9;

}
```

Xcode can't recognise when the image inside the imageview equals an image of whatever name / doesn't update the price.

I tried as well pulling the image straight from the array rather than naming it:

```
 if(
       self.topimage.image == [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesArray objectAtIndex: 1]]){

    self.TopImageView.Price = 200;
}
```

and still the price on the label doesn't change. I'm assuming this is because the price of the imageview doesn't change.

the price on the label is given by:

```
_totalprice = (self.TopImageView.Price + self.MiddleImageView.Price + self.BottomImageView.Price);

    self.Pricelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"£%.0f", _totalprice];
```

all properties are defined and the program runs with no errors. The calculator itself works and correctly sums the 'else' values from my if clauses. All images are under "supporting files" in xcode and I know there can't be an issue with pulling them because they display on the app when pulling them from an array.

Here, for an example, is all the code I have under one button:

```
- (IBAction)Button2:(UIButton *)sender {

    self.clothesindex = self.clothesindex - 1;

    if (self.clothesindex == (-1)) {
        self.clothesindex = 2;
    }
    self.topimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesArray objectAtIndex: self.clothesindex ]];




    if(
       self.topimage.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]){

        self.TopImageView.Price = 200;
    }
    else if(
            self.topimage.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"slacks.png"]){

        self.TopImageView.Price = 400;
    }
    else {
        self.TopImageView.Price = 9;

    }

    _totalprice = (self.TopImageView.Price + self.MiddleImageView.Price + self.BottomImageView.Price);

    self.Pricelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"£%.0f", _totalprice];
}
```

where "top image" is the imageview, "TopImageView" is a class, and "Price" a property of that class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
NSString* imageName = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex: self.clothesindex ];

if([imageName isEqualToString:@"image.png"]){

    self.TopImageView.Price = 200;
}
else if([imageName isEqualToString:@"slacks.png"]){

    self.TopImageView.Price = 400;
}
else {
    self.TopImageView.Price = 9;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare images you can use this method,

```
- (BOOL)image:(UIImage *)image1 isEqualTo:(UIImage *)image2
{
    NSData *data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);
    NSData *data2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image2);

    return [data1 isEqual:data2];
}
```